# Does textfield can overlap the label at JDialog form?

Tags: java, user-interface, variable-assignment

i'm having trouble with my gui... want to have a background image using "label" and then there's an overlapping "text field"... i use "label" (at swing controls) so i can import an image.. and then thinking to overlap a text field.. but that doesn't work, coz every time i drag the text field.. my layout got ruined... can you help me or suggest better solution to my problem.

i just want to show an instruction with a background image in my gui..

thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a [`JLayeredPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) ? From [the Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html), it exactly looks like the required component in your case.

Comment: thanks this works... but do you know how to make my TextArea as an opaque background... i try to custom the code of its background at its properties and this is the method shown jTextArea1.setBackground();

Answer (score 0):

You can add images on a JLabel. If you want to add other components on top of the image you have to add the image to a JPanel. This way you will have layout control. There is a number of steps involved for this solution:

1. Create a class that extends JPanel and includes a reader and and a paintComponent

   ```
   public class ImageJPanel extends JPanel {
       public ImageJPanel() {
          try {
             myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("singer.jpg"));
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              System.out.println("No image! " + ex.getMessage());
          }
       }
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null);
   }

   private BufferedImage myImage;}
   ```
2. Set the layout of your JDialog to BorderLayout.
3. Add another JPanel p, make it non opaque in order to see the image, `p.setOpaque(false);` with the JTextFields, JLabels etc. to your contentpane.
4. Add an ImageJPanel instance to the center of your Border Layout.

Here is a sample constructor for a Tester class that extends JDialog:

```
public Tester() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel myImagePanel = new ImageJPanel();
    add(myImagePanel);
    JPanel workPanel = new JPanel();
    workPanel.setOpaque(false);
    workPanel.add(new JLabel("a label"));
    workPanel.add(new JTextField(10));
    myImagePanel.add(workPanel);
    pack();
}
```